# Finding Smallest Frontier for Graphs of bounded pathwidth

Tags: algorithms, graphs, time-complexity, optimization

Let $G$ be a graph and $X=x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ be an permutation/ordering of the vertex set of $G$. We then let $S_i = \{x_j:j\le i\}$, and $F_i$ be the number vertices $v\in S_i$ that are adjacent to some vertex $u \not\in S_i$. (where $u$ may depend on $v$ and $i$) We finally define $F$ to be a list of values $F_i$ sorted from largest to smallest. e.g. if $F_1=2,F_2=1,F_3=6, F_4=2$ we’d have $F = 6,2,2,1$ (we caution that in reality $F_{i+1}-F_i\le 1$ so the sequence features in the example could not occur)

In general, finding $X$ such that $F$ is [lexicographically](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) minimal is a task which I’d assume is NP-Hard. However, I am curious if there exists a polynomial algorithm to do this for graphs with bounded [pathwidth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathwidth).

Comment: Formal definitions have their place, but occasionally, it helps with descriptions in plain English.  For those of us who's had a long week, what exactly are you asking?  You're not asking for [bandwidth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_bandwidth), [treelength](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X09003941), pathlength, [optimal linear arrangement](http://www.ii.uib.no/~pinar/Cohen-MFCS.pdf)?